# D3 does not plot line charts on Mozilla 37.0.1, whereas line charts are plotted on Chrome 41.0.2272.118 m

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, d3.js, mozilla

After the update from Mozilla to 37.0.1, my previously working application which showcased multi-line charts using D3.js (version 3) library has stopped working. Line charts are not displayed anymore. For previous versions of Firefox (before 37.0.1) application works fine, same applies to Chrome (before 41.0.2272.118 m)
However, for the same line charts, Chrome 41.0.2272.118 is able to display them but i get an error on its developer tool's console -
Error: Invalid value for  attribute d="M536.4224137931035,NaNL536.4224137931035,NaNZ"

Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: can you please post the sample code for plotting??

Comment: Hope there is some problem in your conversion code...

Comment: The `NaN`s indicate that some values are faulty. Look at the chain, the data goes through, before you feed it to the d3 logic.

Comment: The 'NaN' values are the issue. Debug the code that sets the heights for your paths, it is failing to generate valid numbers. I don't really know why it would've worked in the first place, or how Chrome is able to display the charts.

Comment: It could be the interpretation of stings/numbers.  If you're reading in a csv file you **might** have to convert the string to a number; however, without your code it will be difficult to tell.

Comment: @Imperative : The NaN indicates that value is not present for that data point, so D3 shouldnt plot that. For that purpose I've used d3.svg.line().defined(function(d) { return !isNaN(d.population); }).

Comment: The problem is solved. The 'stroke-dasharray' property and the new version of Mozilla had an issue.
Thanks